# Common language runtime detected an invalid program when casting dynamic value to SqlDecimal

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic

I receive this strange exception when dealing with .NET6 method call when casting dynamic variable to nullable SqlDecimal:

```
public class MyClass
{
   public dynamic DynamicValue { get; private set; }
   public SqlDecimal? DecimalValue { get; private set; }

   public MyClass(){}
   public MyClass(dynamic value, SqlDecimal? decimalValue)
   {
      DynamicValue = value;
      DecimalValue = decimalValue;
   }

   public void SetValues(dynamic value, SqlDecimal? decimalValue)
   {
       DynamicValue = value;
       DecimalValue = decimalValue;
   }

   public void SetValues(dynamic value, int? decimalValue)
   {
      DynamicValue = value;
      DecimalValue = decimalValue;
   }
}
```

> System.InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program. at
> System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod.CreateDelegate(Type delegateType,
> Object target) at
> System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.LambdaCompiler.CreateDelegate() at
> System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.LambdaCompiler.Compile(LambdaExpression
> lambda) at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1.Compile() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSiteBinder.BindCore[T](CallSite`1
> site, Object[] args) at
> System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid3[T0,T1,T2](CallSite
> site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)

The test used to prove that are:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Throws_when_cast_from_dynamic_in_constructor()
{
   // arrange
   dynamic dynamicValue = 1;
   SqlDecimal? sqlDecimal = (SqlDecimal?)dynamicValue;
   
   // act
   var @class = new MyClass(dynamicValue, sqlDecimal);
   
   // assert
   Assert.AreEqual(new SqlDecimal(1), @class.DecimalValue);
   Assert.AreEqual(dynamicValue, @class.DynamicValue);
}

[TestMethod]
public void Throw_when_cast_from_dynamic_in_method()
{
   // arrange
   dynamic dynamicValue = 1;
   SqlDecimal? sqlDecimal = (SqlDecimal?)dynamicValue;
   var @class = new MyClass();
   
   // act
   @class.SetValues(dynamicValue, sqlDecimal);
   
   // assert
   Assert.AreEqual(new SqlDecimal(1), @class.DecimalValue);
   Assert.AreEqual(dynamicValue, @class.DynamicValue);
}

[TestMethod]
public void Does_not_throw_when_do_not_cast_from_dynamic_in_method()
{
   // arrange
   dynamic dynamicValue = 1;
   var @class = new MyClass();
   
   // act
   @class.SetValues(dynamicValue, null);
   
   // assert
   Assert.IsNull(@class.DecimalValue);
   Assert.AreEqual(dynamicValue, @class.DynamicValue);
}

[TestMethod]
public void Does_not_throw_when_cast_from_dynamic_in_method_for_other_type()
{
   // arrange
   dynamic dynamicValue = 1;
   int? intValue = (int?)dynamicValue;
   var @class = new MyClass();
   
   // act
   @class.SetValues(dynamicValue, intValue);
   
   // assert
   Assert.AreEqual(new SqlDecimal(1), @class.DecimalValue);
   Assert.AreEqual(dynamicValue, @class.DynamicValue);
}
```

Project settings:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.11.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestAdapter" Version="2.2.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestFramework" Version="2.2.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="3.1.0" />
</ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Might it be a bug in the .net codebase or am I missing something ?

Comment: Well, an invalid program exception is definitely an error in the Expression compile step. So: probably best to report as an issue on the dotnet repo.